# I am getting error when authorization HttpSecurity with spring security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

i want the user with role USER to be able to access the api like "/users" and "/users/{id}", and the ADMIN role to be able to access all, however the api "/users/roles/{id) } is only accessible by ADMIN role, please guide me how to fix it.
here is my code:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth
                        // * AUTH
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        // * USER
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/users/roles/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/users").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        // * POST

                        .anyRequest().authenticated());
```

I still haven't found a fix, According to my code, users with USER role can still access "/users/roles/{id}

Answer (score -1):

Your controller is same for "/users/roles/{id}" and other "/users/**" then you have to mention whole url like "/users/{id}" instead of using * in this 2 lines.

****.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")****

And sometimes requestMatchers does not work so you can try @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_Admin')") on "/users/roles/{id}" method in controller.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).